# JScrollPane scroll only appears at bottom

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have this `JFrame` that has a `JScrollPane` and a `JTextArea` inside it, it works okay but the scroll button only appears at the bottom, I want it to show at the top as default. How can I change this?

```
public class frameMyPasswords extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frameMyPasswords frame = new frameMyPasswords();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public frameMyPasswords() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        //scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition( new Point(0, 0) );
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 45, 414, 194);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        
        JTextArea txtField = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtField);
        
        txtField.setLineWrap(true);
        txtField.setEditable(false);
        txtField.setToolTipText("");
        txtField.setText("LONG TEXT");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `null` layouts, make use of appropriate layout managers, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: You'll find that the scroll bar button positions are determined by the look and feel and aren't otherwise configurable.  You want to change this, then change to a look and feel which supports your desired intent or write your own scroll bar look and feel delegate - neither scenario is particularly desirable and may just end up confusing users who are otherwise use to these things been in pre-determined places - just saying

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. All classes in the JDK follow this convention.  2) Swing has a JTextField and JTextArea. Why would you give your JTextArea a variable name of "textField". That is very confusing. Use meaningful variable names.